# JSF: How validate fields and return error messages by bean validation?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation

I have a contact form and I have some fields that are validated by bean validation, how could I return bean validation error messages after submitting?

For example:

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contact.client.name}"></h:inputText>Name (Required)
    <h:inputText id="email" value="#{contact.client.email}"></h:inputText>E-Mail (Required)
    <h:inputText id="website" value="#{contact.client.website}"></h:inputText>Website (Optional)
    <h:inputText id="text" value="#{contact.client.text}"></h:inputText>Message (Required):

    <h:commandButton value="Send" action="#{contact.sendMessage}" >
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
    </h:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

This is how I'm validating my fields:

```
        // Client.java (model)
    @NotNull(message="Please provide your name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message="Please provide your email")
    @Pattern(regexp = "([^.@]+)(\\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\\.)+([^.@]+)", message = "Invalid e-mail")
    private String email;

    @Pattern(regexp = "(http[s]?://|ftp://)?(www\\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-\\.]+\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$", message = "Not valid URL")
    private String website;

    @NotNull(message="Please provide your message")
    private String text;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either use [`<h:message>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/message.html) which you attach to specific components by `for` attribute which should refer the `id` of the input component:

```html
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{contact.client.name}"></h:inputText>Name (Required)
<h:message for="name" />
<h:inputText id="email" value="#{contact.client.email}"></h:inputText>E-Mail (Required)
<h:message for="email" />
<h:inputText id="website" value="#{contact.client.website}"></h:inputText>Website (Optional)
<h:message for="website" />
<h:inputText id="text" value="#{contact.client.text}"></h:inputText>Message (Required):
<h:message for="text" />
```

or use [`<h:messages/>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/messages.html) to display them all at a single place:

```html
<h:messages />
```

Yes, bean validation messages also ends in there.

Don't forget to ensure that the button's `render` attribute covers them as well.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Glassfish and Eclipse - Hello World - The view](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#CreateJSFHelloWorldInEclipseTheView)

Comment: i follow your tutorial but i have a weird problem, i update my post, please coud you take a look ?

Comment: Is the concrete problem solved? Your new problem is unrelated. It look more like just a CSS issue.

Comment: yeah it is mate, thanks by the help.
i will take a look in my CSS though.

Comment: It mentions it in your tutorial but `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` needs to be set as a `context-param` in the `web.xml` for the `@NotNull` bean validator to work properly. Just for anyone wondering why your bean validation messages aren't appearing (like I was)