# How to get bean validation error message into a JSP page

Tags: jsp, bean-validation

I have read this interesting question [how to pass bean validation error in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985049/jsf-how-validate-fields-and-return-error-messages-by-bean-validation) and I understood how to pass bean validation error into a JSF page. What I ask you is it possible to pass bean validation error using JSP. I'm not using JSF. How can I get bean validation error into a JSP Page in particularly into a form page?

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User implements Serializeable 
{
   @Email(message = "Please insert a valid e-mail")
   private String email;
}
```

Let's suppose to have this entity where I have added a constraint to validate e-mail. I would like to show the error message in a jsp page.

Comment: you might want to check out these links http://www.coderanch.com/t/286390/JSP/java/jsp-form-validation-bean-int and http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/myform.jsp.html

Comment: Unfortunately that is not bean validation. I mean for bean validation putting annotations on the fields and associate to them messages errors to show to the user

Comment: Some Validations can contains keys and scripts that are not available in JSP. You may need to write your own Framework.

Comment: Plain JSP? You are not using a framework? Many frameworks offer integration with BV. If you are not using a framework, how do you call the validation. If you do it manually, you can process the constraint violations yourself and add the appropriate messages into the servlet context.

Comment: @Hardy.I'm using Java EE. 7 with GlassFish it has been validation but I don't know how to get error message in jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

Many frameworks do this (i.e. Spring MVC and Struts 2).

Here's an example of how to do it on Spring:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/